# Can I use caret RFE result for subsequent random forest with CV?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I've been googling and reading alot about my issue but couldn't find a clear answer.

In order to prevent data leakage, I use caret RFE for feature elimination:

```
rfFuncs$summary <- twoClassSummary
#---- rfe control
rfe_ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                       method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 5, # folds
                       repeats = 3, # iterations
                       verbose = TRUE,
                       returnResamp = "all",
                       saveDetails = TRUE)

#---- rfe
set.seed(164)
rfe_profile <- rfe(df_train[,features_name], 
                  df_train[,target_name],
                  sizes = subsets,
                  rfeControl = rfe_ctrl,
                  metric = "ROC",
                  scale = TRUE)

#---- select final features
features_rfe <- predictors(rfe_profile)[1:30]
```

This works well and tells me how many predictors I should use. Let's say I get the result that 60 features works best. However, according to plots and further analysis (e.g. `pickSizeTolerance`) I know I can use the first 30 features and still having good performance of predictions.

Now, can I use these 30 features (=`features_rfe`) in a subsequent model training step (see code below) since I don't touch the test set until after this step? Or would I introduce data leakage with this step because the model gets trained with pre-selected best features?

```
#---- random forest control
rf_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                        number = 5, # folds
                        verbose = TRUE,
                        returnResamp = "all",
                        classProbs = TRUE,
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

#---- random forest grid search
rf_grid <-  expand.grid(mtry = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20))

#---- random forest
set.seed(10)
rf_caret_train <- train(df_train[,features_rfe], 
                df_train[,target_name], 
                method = "rf", 
                trControl = rf_ctrl,
                tuneGrid = rf_grid,
                metric = "ROC",
                verbose = TRUE)
#---- make predictions
rf_caret_test_raw <- predict(rf_caret_train, df_test[,features_rfe], type='raw', scale=TRUE)
```

I hope you cann help me.

Best,
Troji

Comment: Since this is a more ML/stats geared question than on code itself, might I suggest moving it to StatsExchange?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. You're right. I've posted the question there:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472231/can-i-use-caret-rfe-result-for-subsequent-random-forest-with-cv